# Why is a my List.Intersect returning different results than a Where(List.Contains)?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working on an Active Directory synchronization project, and I'm trying to compare a list of users from AD with a list of users stored in a database. I have implemented a custom `UserPrincipal` (which I inventively called `NetworkUserPrincipal`) to expose some properties we need to set during on-boarding. `NetworkUserPrincipal` also implements `IEqualityComparer<NetworkUserPrincipal>`.

I'm also working on unit tests with small sample sizes, and I'm trying to work out a process to skip over everyone whose information hasn't changed. Here's my test:

```
// a static list of two users
List<NetworkUserPrincipal> expected = JobTestData.InternalActiveDirectoryData.SynchronizedUsers
// returns only one user.
List<NetworkUserPrincipal> actual = _activeDirectoryUsers.Intersect(_databaseUsers).ToList(); // returns only one user.

Assert.IsTrue(expected.All(_databaseUsers.Contains)); // true
Assert.IsTrue(expected.All(_activeDirectoryUsers.Contains)); // true
Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual(actual)); // false
```

However, if I change `_activeDirectoryUsers.Intersect(_databaseUsers).ToList();` to `_activeDirectoryUsers.Where(_databaseUsers.Contains).ToList();`, my final test passes.

When I debug the unit test, I put a breakpoint in my Equals override function, and it only gets called once in the `Intersect` scenario.

What's going on?

Comment: Are you sure you want `SequenceEqual`? Is `JobTestData.InternalActiveDirectoryData.SynchronizedUsers` a list that has only the one expected user?

Comment: Are you implementing `GetHashCode()` apart from `Equal`? I recall `Intersect` having problems with the default object implementation of `GetHashCode()`

Comment: I'm not writing an answer, because I'm not sure why this happens (would need to test throughoutly), but check [without GetHashCode](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8CRzwK) and [with GetHashCode](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ymDcZA). See that the `Intersect` list is empty on the first case. *Any* (even non correct) implementation of `GetHashCode` seems to get the job done. Even just a `return 0` does, but no-implementation (that is, it's using the `object` one) doesn't work.

Comment: @Jcl - bingo. You got it exactly right. If you'll post that as an answer, I'm happy to take down mine and accept yours.

Comment: @jwiscarson *`NetworkUserPrincipal` also implements `IEqualityComparer<NetworkUserPrincipal>`"* This gives you absolutely nothing. Make sure it implements `IEquatable<NetworkUserPrincipal>` instead or implement `IEqualityComparer<NetworkUserPrincipal>` in a separate class and pass it as third argument to the `Intersect`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a correct implementation of `GetHashCode()` to work with `Intersect`. Not sure why, but it does have problems without it.

[Fiddle without GetHashCode()](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8CRzwK)

[Fiddle with GetHashCode()](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ymDcZA)

<strike>Seems any implementation (even a non-correct one) of `GetHashCode` does, just not the default's object one.</strike>

***Edit***: as @ScottChamberlain explained in the comments, not any non-correct implementation will work, it does need a correct implementation (where every equal object returns an equal hash code). It does not need to be *efficient*, just correct.

Comment: Thanks. I always implement GetHashCode as well. I'm used to writing code to compare strings and ignore casing, and I just never considered doing that in a GetHashCode function.

Comment: The reason it has problems is `Intersect` works by creating a `HashSet<T>` (well actually a `Set<T>` but that is a private class) then loads the first list then goes through the second list trying to find any that exist in the set. If it finds one it returns it to the `IEnumerable<T>`. That hash set requires `GetHashCode()` to work.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain as I understand it, it requires `GetHashCode` to be efficient, but It should work with any implementation since it should call `Equal` if the objects are on the same hash bucket. So not sure why it doesn't work... [check this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I1XaPG), I return a direct `0` on `GetHashCode()` yet it still works because `Equals` returns the correct result.

Comment: @jwiscarson Often when comparing classes with strings I keep  a `private StringComparer s = StringComparer.OrdnalIgnorseCase` then in the `Equals(` I can do `s.Equals(x.StringProp, y.StringProp)`  and in the GetHashCode I do `s.GetHashCode(x.StringProp)`. That way if I ever want to change how it compares I just change the comparer that gets created with the class.

Comment: @Jcl If you don't implement GetHashCode() the default implmentation makes everyone in to their own bucket by using the object id given to it by the CLR, it does not put everyone in to the same bucket. However that was not the OP's problem.

Comment: Ah, that's a great idea. This one question has been a treasure trove of new ideas.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain ah, I understand now, makes perfect sense. I've edited the question to reflect that and acknowledge your comment

Answer (score 2):

`SequenceEqual` requires both lists to have the same content **and the same order**. The problem is likley the order is diffrent. use [`CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243779.aspx) instead, it does not care about the order of the collection.

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expected,actual);
```

Also, `Intersect` does perform a implicit `Distinct()` on the result. if you have two of the same item `expected.All(_databaseUsers.Contains)` would pass but the two lists could have different counts.

Comment: Your answer actually hits upon why I use such a small set of data initially. I had forgotten about CollectionAssert, actually, so I appreciate your answer as well. I used SequenceEquals because I'm ordering my data on its way out of the DB anyway, but the more I think about your answer, the more I realize that's a smelly reason to use this in unit testing.